# Integral independent of the parameter $y$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the integral
$$\int_a^b \frac{K(x)}{1+yx^2}dx$$
where $a$, $b$ are fixed constants and $y$ is a parameter.

Question:

Is there a smooth function $K(x)\neq 0$,
s.t.
$$\int_a^b \frac{K(x)}{1+yx^2}dx=\int_a^b \frac{xK(x)}{1+yx^2}dx=0,$$
for arbitrary $y$?

For example, when $K(x)=x$ and $[a,b]=[-1,1]$
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{1+yx^2}dx=\ln (1+yx^2)/(2y)|_{-1}^1=0$$
which is independent of $y$.

I don't know if there exists a function $K(x)$ satisfying the conditions in my question above.

Comment: you seem to mix $dx$ and $dy$... what are exactly the conditions ? because in your example there is $dy$, but in your condition there is no $dy$. Moreover, what mean $K$ independent of $y$ ? The simple fact that you write $K(x)$ means that $K$ is not dependent of $y$... but maybe you have something else in mind if you write $K(x)$ and precise that $K$ is independent of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could try taking a derivative with respect to $y$ and commuting with the integral to derive a condition for independence. Set

$$P(y)=\int\limits_a^b\frac{K(x)}{1+yx^2}dx$$

Then if $\frac{dP}{dy}=0$ we have functional independence. Well assuming $a$ and $b$ are indepenent of $y$,

$$\frac{dP}{dy}=\int\limits_a^bK(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{1}{1+yx^2}\right)dx=-\int\limits_a^b\frac{K(x)x^2}{(1+yx^2)^2}dx$$

So the condition becomes

$$\int\limits_a^b\frac{K(x)x^2}{(1+yx^2)^2}dx=0 \tag{1}$$

In particular if K(x) is chosen to be an odd function and the limits chosen such that $b=-a$ as you did in your example we can see $P(y)=0$ always regardless of the value of y, this is why your example works.

To answer this question in general however it might be a good idea to try an solve $(1)$. One way of doing this is to solve for the integrand being zero, however this results in $K(x)=0$. I do not suspect there is a solution to $(1)$ outside of the special cases I have mentioned for nonzero $K$ independent of $y$.

If you allow your limits to depend on $y$ then there will be much more freedom in the resulting condition for independence and thus more likely for such a K(x) to exist.